# Why onChildChanged() method is working directly when i add new data in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

here is my code:

```
 @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull @NotNull final DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable String previousChildName) {

            if(playerGenerator.getPlayerById(snapshot.getKey()) == null)
                return;
            if(playerGenerator.getPlayerById(snapshot.getKey()).hero == null)
                return;

            if(snapshot.child("targetId").getValue(String.class) != "null")
            {
                Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        playerGenerator.getPlayerById(snapshot.getKey()).targetHero = playerGenerator.getPlayerById(snapshot.child("targetId").getValue(String.class)).hero;

                    }
                });
            }
```

Data is adding as i want. But it is working directly. What i mean? For example, i want to update my hero AFTER data uploaded to database. But in this case, my hero is updating itself directly (before data uploaded to database). So what should i do for trigger this method after data uploaded to database?

Comment: Obviously because your data is not saved into database immediately after saving data and is only uploaded when proper connection is established till then it is stored in local cache so onChildChanged is called because database child is changed Refer [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-prioritizing-the-local-cache) for more

Comment: @IzhanAli thanks for information, but how can i close that? i checked that site, but i couldn't find something. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase clients fire local events for local write operations right away. This is known as latency compensation, as it means the users always sees their own changes right away.

If you want to reflect in your UI that the data was written to the back-end database, you can [add a completion listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback) to the write operation.

Comment: Thanks! That is what i needed.